# undefined method `visit' - RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I currently have a test that doesn't seen to have the ability to visit particular paths. This test is a request spec and this is my first one, as far as I can tell request spec are similar to feature test and can user capybara to do things like `visit` and `fill_in`. But right now I can't get this request spec to even visit a path. Is there something I should know about request specs? I'll post my code and see if you see anything strange?

SPEC:

```
  require "spec_helper"

describe "Mailchimp" do
  describe "Manage list" do
    it "adds new subscriber to list" do
      VCR.use_cassette "mailchimp/subscriber" do
        visit new_subscriber_path
        expect {
          fill_in "first_name", with: "John"
          fill_in "last_name", with: "Mayer"
          fill_in "phone_number", with: "61615551233"
          fill_in "email", with: "john@rowster.com"
          click_button "Sign Up"
        }.to change(Subscriber, :count).by(1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Let me know if you need to see anything else. Thank You!

Comment: what happens if you change 'spec_helper' to 'rails_helper'?

Comment: Nothing. Same error. Thank for pointing that out though

Comment: I'm not an r-spec expert but don't all RSpec commaands start with an `RSpec.something "" do` block to launch rspec?  I'd also see if i works if you make it independent of VCR ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Request specs used to be the same thing as feature specs in earlier versions of RSpec, but things have since changed.

Request specs are designed for you to hit the full stack via an HTTP request and inspect details from the `response`. You use methods like `get`, `post`, `patch`, and `delete` to interact with your application.

An example request spec:

```
get "/users/#{user.id}"
expect(response.body).to include user.full_name
```

Feature specs are driven by Capybara and allow you to hit the full stack via elements of the interface. If you want to hit a specific URL, that's when you use `visit`.

Your question includes an example of a feature spec, so I don't really need to echo it in this answer. My piece of advice related to your code would be to change it so that it's inspecting the interface and not how it changes the database.

(So I guess I will echo your code after all. :))

```
require "rails_helper"

feature "Mailchimp" do
  describe "Manage list" do
    scenario "adds new subscriber to list" do
      VCR.use_cassette "mailchimp/subscriber" do
        visit new_subscriber_path
        fill_in "first_name", with: "John"
        fill_in "last_name", with: "Mayer"
        fill_in "phone_number", with: "61615551233"
        fill_in "email", with: "john@rowster.com"
        click_button "Sign Up"
        expect(page).to have_content "You have successfully subscribed to our service"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Chris! I just have one question. I was using a Tut by Rails cast and he is clearly using the Capybara conventions in his test. Was this wrong on the tutorial side? I guess I'm a little confused by that.

Comment: Railscasts are still very valuable, but you need to be careful because they are slowly becoming outdated. I think I know which Railscast you are referring to, and yes, this aspect of RSpec has changed since the screecast was recorded.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it

Comment: No problem. Because I can't keep my mouth shut, I updated the answer to include a small critique of your example feature spec.